# How to generate pdf from blade view using phpwkhtmltopdf library?

Tags: laravel, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am doing this project where I need to generate a pdf report for quarterly transactions.
I have created the blade view files and I am able to generate the pdf's using wkhtmltopdf library with shell_exec(). Here my code for that:

```
public function generate_report($quarter, $year){

    $url_home = 'http://localhost.welcomehome.com/testreport/';
    $temp_path = storage_path().'/temp/';
    $stmt = ' ';
    $stmt = 'wkhtmltopdf --margin-top 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-right 0 '.$url_home.'page1/'.$quarter.'/'.$year.' '.$temp_path.'page1.pdf ';
   //appending similar strings to $stmt
    shell_exec ($stmt);
   }
```

Now, In this approach I need to make an http call from my server to itself, which in theory should not be required for this problem. I came across this library 
[phpwkhtmltopdf library](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

which is a wrapper around wkhtmltopdf. I can get it to work doing:

```
$pdf = new Pdf($url_home.'page1/'.$quarter.'/'.$year);
if (!$pdf->saveAs(.$temp_path.'page1.pdf')) {
    echo $pdf->getError();
}
```

But, this would be same as above, I want to use the blade view files to generate pdf without calling the urls. But, I can't get this to work:

```
 public function generate_report_v2($quarter,$year)
 {
    $pdf = new Pdf(view('research_reports/about',['quarter' => $quarter, 'year' => $year]););
    $temp_path = storage_path().'/temp/';
    if(!$pdf->saveAs($temp_path.'page.pdf'))
    {
        echo $pdf->getError();
    }
 }
```

It gives me the error:

```
You need to specify at least one input file, and exactly one output file Use - for stdin or stdout Name: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt) Synopsis: wkhtmltopdf [GLOBAL OPTION]... [OBJECT]... Document objects: wkhtmltopdf is able to put several objects into the output file, an object is either a single webpage, a cover webpage or a table of content. The objects are put into the output......and some more lines.
```

Please let me know if anyone generated pdfs using this library with blade view files. I seem to have stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Try `view('research_reports.about'` with dot here instead of slash

Comment: Unless that view file has **all** its resources inlined, then the browser engine in the pdf lib will need to make a bunch of http requests anyway - why do you want to avoid http?

Comment: @GONG Tried but didn't work out. Same error. :(

Comment: I always use dompdf for making pdfs make's it really easy. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: @Maantje. Okay. I will try out dompdf.

Comment: Dompdf just does not make PDFs like wkhtmltopdf. It leaves off certain background colors,glyph icons and images. Would keep using the wkhtmltopdf with shell script to generate PDFs until I find a better solution that gives exact PDFs.